# Central Manager's didDiscoverPeripheral Method Not Being Called For Non-Apple Beacon

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working with a proprietary beacon. I have full access to the beacon's code and am able to set the Manufacturer ID as I like. If I set the ID to Apple's (i.e. make it an iBeacon) then the Location Manager is able to detect the beacon's region and is able to range the beacon. If I set the ID to another manufacturer (i.e. make it a "normal" beacon) then the Central Manager's didDiscoverPeripheral method **is not called**. It is my understanding that iOS treats "normal" beacons in the same way as any other BLE peripheral. Can anyone suggest some possible causes?

1. I am using iOS 9 and swift
2. My application is discovering several other BLE peripherals. Hence I am confident that my application's use of the core bluetooth framework is correct.

Comment: How do you scan ? Does an app like LightBlue detect the peripheral when you change the manufacturer id ?

Comment: @Larme I scan by specifying no service uuids - hence, discover everything. And, indeed, I do discover some peripherals, just not the beacon. I am unfamiliar with LightBlue but will give it a try and report back.

Comment: @Larme Hmmm, I'm not liking LightBlue very much. However, when I use a Windows Bluetooth Sniffer I see both the iBeacon and the "normal" beacon. All of the advertising data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect manufacturer advertisements, I believe you have to pass in a `nil` for the `serviceUUIDs` array.  Example below:

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil,
  options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true]
)
```

Comment: Is your app in the foreground or background? You can't detect mfg advertisements in the background with CoreBluetooth.